# DÚVIDA DE HERANÇA EM JAVA(PEQUENO)

Tags: java, herança

Você foi contratado para desenvolver um sistema
para uma oficina de motos, carros e caminhões. A sua
primeira tarefa será construir um conjunto de classes para
representar os veículos que serão atendidos na oficina.
Considerando os conceitos de herança,
encapsulamento e composição vistos nas aulas, crie um
conjunto de classes para esses veículos:
– Um veículo pode ser uma moto, carro ou caminhão;
– Cada veículo possui uma placa;
– Os veículos contêm duas, quatro ou mais rodas;
• Cada roda possui um diâmetro, largura e um número de série;
– Cada veículo possui vários parafusos;
• Um parafuso tem um diâmetro, altura e um número de série.
SÓ PRECISO TER UMA IDÉIA DE COMO CRIAR ESTAS CLASSES ULTILIZANDO HERANÇA

Comment: Cara, é bom tu dar uma lida antes ou assistir uns vídeos sobre herança, não sei qual seu conhecimento no assunto, mas tente estudar um pouco, caso queira: https://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-e-aplicando-heranca-em-java/24544

Comment: A "ideia" já está no anunciado. Qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Acredito que a dúvida dele seja: "Quais classes devo criar e com quais atributos"

Answer (score 1):

Indo por partes, acredito que você deve criar uma classe pai `Veículos`, com os atributos: `placa`, `roda`(que deve ser do tipo `rodas`) e `parafuso` (que deve ser do tipo parafuso);

Criar as subclasses `motos`, `carros` e `caminhões` -- Essas subclasses devem estender a classe pai;

Eu criaria uma classe `rodas` que recebe os atributos  `diâmetro`, `largura` e `número de série`;

Criaria também a classe parafuso que recebe os atributos `diâmetro`, `altura` e `número de série`;

Eu estou te dando uma "ideia", mas você deve estudar várias coisas antes de fazer o seu trabalho ou tarefa, não sei, coisas como: `encapsulamento`, aprenda criar um `objeto de uma classe`, criar os métodos `get` e `set` para cada atributo (deve aprender também a usar esses métodos), deve aprender `extends` também, acredito que seja isso, boa sorte.

Comment: eu ja sei todos os conceitos, a questão é que eu fiz isso tudo que voce falou mas o professor disse que nao estava totalmente correto e como é um desafio,elenão falou onde estava o erro

Comment: a maior dúvida msm era qual classe herdava de qual, mas eu fiz isso msm que vc falou int agora n sei msm onde errei ja que ele não falou

Comment: Não tem mais descrição? nenhum método? talvez seja algo como tornar os atributos private, mas não faço ideia, me conte quando ele disser qual era o erro

Comment: tipo na classe veiculo tenho o atributo placa que é de todos, eu passei no construtor da classe placa o valor dela ,tudo normal, e como todas as classes herdam de veiculo eu teria que chamar o construtor de veiculo dentro das outras classes como carro, moto etc

Comment: public class veiculos {
 private long placa;
 

 public veiculos(long placa) {
  this.placa = placa;
 }

Comment: public class carro extends veiculos {

 public carro(long placa) {
  super(placa);
 }

}
//e assim ficou minha classe carro como as outras tbm, deve ter algo a mais nelas?

Comment: é provável que o construtor na classe veículo não seja necessário, a classe veículo deve ser do tipo abstrata, pois não vai ser instanciada acredito eu. Acredito também que desse jeito está bom, n consigo imaginar o que o seu professor deseja

Comment: public class carro extends veiculos { public carro(long placa) { this.placa; } } //Eu faria dessa maneira pois não é necessário construtor na classe pai

Comment: esse é o resto do enunciado

Comment: Além disso, na classe que representa o veículo crie métodos
para adicionar, buscar (por numero de série), excluir (a partir
do número de série) cada elemento que compõe o veículo.

Comment: mas esses metodos n interferem na ultlizaçao da herança pois afinal eu só vou chamar eles, e creio que estao certos pois ja criei eles varias vezes

Comment: @JeffHenrique, sua reposta ficaria mais bem estruturada se você criasse as classes e não apenas informasse os atributos, dessa forma, tanto o problema dele como a reposta, se tornariam mais conclusivos

Comment: @IvanSilva o que ele pediu foi uma "ideia" de como criar, mostrei minha ideia de como poderia ser feito, mas obrigado pela dica